# Error when installing Microsoft Playwright

Tags: python, pip, playwright

I'm getting this error:

```
At line:1 char:1
+ playwright install
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (playwright:String) [],CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm installing it using pip, for use in python

Comment: `playwright` doesn’t appear to be installed on your system, or at least not in a PATH that your PowerShell is configured for. Can you elaborate as to what *specifically* about this error message is confusing to you…?

Comment: you did do the `pip install playwright` first right?

Comment: @kindall Yep, that's why I'm puzzled.

Comment: Did you get a warning like this from pip? `WARNING: The script playwright.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.` If so, add that directory to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need playwright added to your PATH.

However, a better way to do this (if python is added to your path) without adding it to your PATH is by running:

```
python -m playwright install
```

This runs the playwright module as a script. Use `python -h` for more information on these flags, and `python -m playwright` for more information on the flags supported specifically by playwright